# Is there a way to create a "copy post" link?

Tags: php, functions

Much like the "edit" link when viewing a post, is here a "copy post" function I can include with my theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Duplicate Post is what you need. You have the function that you need in http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/duplicate-post/other_notes/

Answer (score 1):

Didnt try myself but you can try:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/duplicate-post/

[image]

Let us know the result :)